# Python using multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
import threading
from time import time

def count(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(i)


def count2(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(i)

def count3(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(i)





x = threading.Thread(target=count,args=(10,))
x.start()

y  = threading.Thread(target=count2,args=(10,))
y.start()

y  = threading.Thread(target=count3,args=(10,))
y.start()
```

i decided to learn python multithreading , i found this code and output is

```
1
2
3
1
4
1
2
2
3
3
5
4
6
5
7
8
6
9
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
7
8
9
10
10
```

can anyone explain me why is this output ? and how it's works ?
i want to run multithreading with selenium.

what is best way to understand how multithreading works in python3

Comment: Well, this code launches 3 threads which print numbers from 1 to 10 each. Threads work parallel, so output has no order.

Comment: Can you please clarify what parts of the output you *do* understand? Presumably you have some expectation for what the program you written does, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks normal and functioning properly. The "thread" you can understand as it prepares different paths for the programming flow to run together. The system will not be in order because running parallel. If let's say you want to be in a certain sequence, then you need to have some workaround to make it looks more "presentable", as the Event function "Event.Set()" in Python.